# Java invoke thread inside it's run()

Tags: java, thread-safety

I wrote a thread class that checks the socket connection to the server by sending a small string every one second.

`begin()` method executes the thread.

After connection is lost, the thread tries to connect again.

My question is if it's ok to re-run by `begin()` the thread inside the `run()` method like I did (see below).

```
public void begin() {  
   Check = new Thread(this);
   Check.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
   Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
   while (Check==thisThread) {
      try {
         oos.writeObject("a");
         // oos.flush();

         synchronized (this) {
            while (pleaseWait) {
               try {
                  System.out.println("waiting");    
                  wait();
                  System.out.println("not waiting");      
               } 
               catch (Exception e) {
                  System.err.println("Thread is interrupted: "+e.getMessage());
               }
            }
         }
         sleep(1000);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
              v = new Visual("The connection is lost. The system will try to reconnect now.");
              this.end();
              try {
                 Server=ClientLogin.checkingServers(); //returns the reachable server string address
                 socket = new Socket(Server, ServerPort);
                 System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
                 oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                 begin();
                 v = new Visual("The system is reconnected.");
              }
              catch(UnknownHostException uhe){  
                 System.out.println("Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage());
                 v = new Visual("The system has failed to reconnected.");
              }
              catch (IOException ioe) {
                 System.out.println("The system cannot connect to servers: " + ioe.getMessage());
                 v = new Visual("The system has failed to reconnected.");
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("The system has failed to reconnect: " + e.getMessage());
                 v = new Visual("The system has failed to reconnected.");
              }
          }
   }
}

public void end() {
   Check = null;
}
```

Comment: You are not overriding run of the Check...

Comment: but it is finished right after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any reason why that wouldn't work, but it looks kinda messy.  You may have to declare `Check` as `volatile` to ensure that the loop always reads the current value, for those times when the new thread overwrites it.

IMHO a better approach would be a separate "supervisor" thread which is responsible for starting one of these threads, and then uses `Thread.join()` to wait for it to die, at which point it can start it up again.

In this way your main thread's logic can concentrate on exactly what it's *supposed* to do, without needing to have any "self awareness".

Answer (score 1):

First, the code is not thread safe. The "Check" field is written by one thread but read by another, but it is not synchronised. There is no guarantee that the new started thread is going to see the updated value of "Check", i.e. the new thread will get the old thread's reference when checking "Check==thisThread" and do the wrong thing,

This particular problem can be fixed by making "Check" field volatile. It makes sure when it is updated, every thread will see the new value.

It is not "wrong" to call "begin()" in the run() method. However I wouldn't recommend it because you created a recursive call here effectively. There is a good chance you will get it wrong and fall into infinite loop. Try the simple design below. It uses a while loop instead of recursion.

```
package com.thinkinginobjects;

public class HeathChecker {

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        boolean success = checkHeath();
        if (!success) {
            //log and re-establish connection
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkHeath() {
    try {
        oos.writeObject("a");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it is ok, however why do you need to start a thread every time? Isn't it better to use Timer and TimerTask?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html